# create special floating menu in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, menu, floating

I'm going to create an special floating menu like this site:
http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-toscana/menu

as you can see, Categories and Your Order menus float in screen so that their position is almost always the same, and they always stick to top of screen (of course after you scroll the page down), how can I create this effect in ASP.NET? I've set my menu style position property as fixed, but in this way, my menu always has the same position, I want my menus to stick to top of screen

Comment: Post some code.It will be helpful.

Comment: Did you get any help?Check my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if ASP.NET has such feature by default. Never seen something like that in it. But it could be done easily with CSS position:fixed placed on top most div of your menu block or using plugin like [this](http://simianstudios.com/portamento/), for instance. Please note that position:fixed may cause problems in old browsers

Answer (score 1):

Hello Ali you must add stylesheet in order to float your menu, but you don't have property in order to float your menu basicaly

Comment: @Candie He wants the menu to be fixed when you scroll.Why the need for float:left or float:right?

Comment: i gave sample of floatting usage

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the position of the `div` to `position:fixed`.

By doing that its position will be `relative` to the position to browser window and it will appear to be fixed.

Here is **[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgX47/)**

**[More on CSS Fixed Positioning.](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=1&tok=z29n6lBqF0SfVALq2SBTyA&pq=fixed%20position&cp=1&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=css%20fixed%20position&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=cfixed%20position&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3d6f376293f03481&biw=1024&bih=679)**